# Primefaces picklist. Setter for DualListModel removes source and target

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having a problem with my picklist. Showing the source and targets works, but when the commandbutton is pressed it calles the setter of the picklist and empties the source and target of the picklist. After that it calls the method connectTags().

What is the reason of this behavior and how could I solve this?

```
<h:form>
    <p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{employeeEditController.dualListTags}"
        var="tag" itemLabel="#{tag.value}" itemValue="#{tag}">
        <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="targetCaption">Connected</f:facet>  
    </p:pickList>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{employeeEditController.connectTag()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@Named(value = "employeeEditController")
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeEditController implements Serializable, IEditController {
    private Employee selectedEmployee;
    private DualListModel<Tags> dualListTags;

@Inject
private EmployeeFacade employeeFacade;
@Inject
private CompanyFacade companyFacade;
@Inject
private TagFacade tagFacade;

public void setSelectedEmployee(Employee selectedEmployee) {
    System.out.println("setSelectedEmployee called. Value: " + selectedEmployee.getFirstName());
    this.selectedEmployee = selectedEmployee;
    this.refreshDualList();
}

private void refreshDualList(){
    List<Tags> source = (List<Tags>) this.getCompanyTags();
    List<Tags> target = (List<Tags>) this.getTags();
    System.out.println("refreshDualList called. \nSource: " + source.size() +
            "Target: " + target.size());
    this.dualListTags = new DualListModel<Tags>(source, target);
}

public Collection<Tags> getTags(){
    Collection<Tags> retVal;
    if(this.selectedEmployee != null){
        retVal = this.selectedEmployee.getTags();
        if(retVal == null){
           retVal = new ArrayList<Tags>();
        } 
    } else{
        System.out.println("selected emp is null");
        retVal = new ArrayList<Tags>();
    }
    return retVal;
}

public Collection<Tags> getCompanyTags() {
    Collection<Tags> retVal = new ArrayList<Tags>();
    if(this.companyID == null){
        String userstr = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
        this.companyID = this.companyFacade.getCompanyIDByUser(userstr);
    }
    retVal = this.tagFacade.getTagsFromCompanyID(companyID);
    return retVal;
}

public void save(){
    if(this.selectedEmployee != null){
        System.out.println("Save called. Value: " + this.selectedEmployee.getFirstName());
        this.employeeFacade.edit(this.selectedEmployee);
    }
}

public void connectTag() {
    if(this.dualListTags != null){
        System.out.println("connectTag() called.\n" + "source: " + this.dualListTags.getSource().size() + 
                "\ntarget: " + this.dualListTags.getTarget().size());
        this.selectedEmployee.setTags((Collection<Tags>)this.dualListTags.getTarget());
        this.save();
    }
}

public DualListModel<Tags> getDualListTags() {
    System.out.println("getDualList called. \nSource :" + this.dualListTags.getSource().size()
            + "\nTargets: " + this.dualListTags.getTarget().size());
    return this.dualListTags; 
}

public void setDualListTags(DualListModel<Tags> dualListTags) {
    System.out.println("setDualList called. \nSource :" + this.dualListTags.getSource().size()
            + "\nTargets: " + this.dualListTags.getTarget().size());
    this.dualListTags = dualListTags;
    System.out.println("setDualList called after set. \nSource :" + this.dualListTags.getSource().size()
                + "\nTargets: " + this.dualListTags.getTarget().size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the showcase example work for you? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf Build further on that step by step until it fails the same way and you've got the cause.

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Save" onsuccess="#{employeePicklist.connectTags()}"/> The connectTags method gets the source and target from the duallist saved in the controller. But the setter is called and empties the duallist

Comment: What does `connectTags()` return - is that returning JavaScript to be run in the browser?

Comment: If you really want to solve this, post a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If you have modified your code according to the comments here, you must apply the changes to your post, otherwise it is either misleading, or irrelenvat. Also, a good idea will be to cleanup your code so that the problematic areas are present. If you're not sure whether some of the other code (the one you should omit here) causes the problem, then make an example and test it before submitting the question.

Comment: You are both right. I will post an update here soon.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it seems that the solution is to impement a custom converter for the entity you use in picklist.

This is how my custom converter looks like:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "vehicleGroupConverter")
public class VehicleGroupConverter implements Converter {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{vehiclesBean}")
    private VehiclesBean vehiclesBean;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        long groupId = Long.parseLong(value);
        List<AssetCategory> groups = vehiclesBean.getVehicleGroups();
        for (AssetCategory group : groups) {
            if (group.getCategoryId() == groupId) {
                return group;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        return Long.toString(((AssetCategory) value).getCategoryId());
    }

    public void setVehiclesBean(VehiclesBean vehiclesBean) {
        this.vehiclesBean = vehiclesBean;
    }

}
```

And this is the picklist template part:

```
<p:pickList id="vehicleGroups" 
        value="#{vehiclesBean.selectedVehicleGroups}" 
        var="group" 
        itemLabel="#{group.name}" 
        itemValue="#{group}"
        converter="#{vehicleGroupConverter}"
        styleClass="pf-panel-grid"
        style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">#{i18n['label-available-groups']}</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{i18n['label-assigned-groups']}</f:facet>
</p:pickList>
```

Comment: Why is the `Converter` a `ManagedBean`?

Comment: In general there is no reason for that. It was simply convenient in the specific app I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

Sets duallistmodel when source or target not empty:

```
public void setDualListTags(DualListModel<Tags> dualListTags) {
    if(this.dualListTags.getSource().size()!=0 && this.dualListTags.getTarget().size()!=0) {
        this.dualListTags = dualListTags;
    }
}
```